# Организация очереди из QTcpSocket

Tags: база-данных, qt, клиент-сервер

Имеется приложение написанное на Qt: сервер, который общается с бд, клиенты, которые подключаются к серверу(порядка 50). Клиенты подключаются к серверу, отправляют ему запросы в виде чистого SQL(запросы самые разнообразные: вставка, удаление, выборка), сервер передаёт запросы в БД, получает ответ, отсылает ответ клиенту, после чего коннект закрывается. Так как все клиенты работают параллельно с БД, то как я думаю, многопоточный доступ реализовать невозможно. Поэтому есть идея реализовать подключение очередью - но тут я не представляю как это сделать? Запустить отдельный поток на сервере, который будет постоянно крутиться? Или весь подход такой цепочки: "клиент(запросы в чистом SQL) - сервер - БД" изначально не правильный?

Comment: Не понимаю, чего вы хотите в результате добиться. Потенциально, очередь может работать очень медленно.

Comment: Может и медленно, а как ещё? Если делать не очередью возможен конфликт при одновременном доступе к БД, разве не так?

Comment: @user280467, не пойму, вы что ли транзакции пытаетесь изобрести? Посмотрите [это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9)